# Proof that there are neither maximal elements nor minimal elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

Let $X=\{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$ and endow $X\times X$ with the order $$(x, y)\leq (z, t)\Leftrightarrow x|z\ \textrm{and}\ t|y.$$

I'm supposed to find the minimal and maximal elements of $X\times X$ with respect to this order.

**Conjecture.** There are no minimal and no maximal elements.

**Proof attempt:** I'm going to show that no pair $(p, q)$ can be a minimal element. In fact, notice:

$$(p, 2q)\leq (p, q)$$ 
since $p|p$ and $q|2q$. But, $2q\neq q$ once $q$ is a positive integer. Therefore, given $(p, q)$ there is always a pair which preceeds $(p, q)$ (namely, $(p, 2q)$).

Analogously, there are no maximal elements. In fact, no pair $(p, q)$ can be a maximal element for:

$$(p, q)\leq (2p, q)$$
and $2p\neq p$ once $p$ is a positive integer.

Are my arguments correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot =)